# Replace Function - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, replace

```
 strTemp = MyStream.ReadLine.Split()
```

I am confuse of using .replace and .split. I'm trying to change the tabs and spaces combined of a single line of a text file, how can i achieve this?

Comment: change the Tab and Space chars to *what*?  Why split it?

Comment: change them to single spacing from each word (e.g Test1[space]Test2[space]Test3[space]) I'm confused of what to use either replace or split.

Comment: Split isnt really needed.  Replace the tabs and replace "  " (double space) with single space.  Use `Contains()` to see what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don'n know exactly what do you want but below 2 code snippets can help you:

1.just use `Replace`:

```
'remove tab characters
Dim outString as String = inString.Replace(Constants.vbTab, "")
```

or

```
'remove spacec haracters
Dim outString as String = inString.Replace(" ", "")
```

2.use an `Split` then use `Replace` in a loop through resulted array by Split:

```
'split with tabs(or spaces) or spaces
Dim arrayStr() As String = inString.Split(Constants.vbTab)
'remove space(or tabs) characters
For i As Integer = 0 To arrayStr.Length - 1
 arrayStr(i) = arrayStr(i).Replace(" ", "")
Next
```

Comment: I've experimented with your snippets and added to my code and i came up with this code
    strTemp = MyStream.ReadLine.Split(New [Char]() {" "c, CChar(vbTab), CChar(vbNewLine)}) when i use tabs to separate words it does the job. but when i combine random spaces with tabs to separate each word it displays only the first word.

Comment: then you should clarified your question more and didn't waste our time

Comment: You didn't waste your , your suggestions enhance my code.